# Scraping on Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram, screen-scraping

I wanted to get the caption, no. of likes and comments of the recent 10 images of a particular user.
Using below code I am just able to get the latest one.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json, time, re
phantomjs_path = r'C:\Users\ravi.janjwadia\Desktop\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe'
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(phantomjs_path)
user = "barackobama"     
browser.get('https://instagram.com/' + user)
time.sleep(0.5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
script_tag = soup.find('script',text=re.compile('window\._sharedData'))
shared_data = script_tag.string.partition('=')[-1].strip(' ;')
result = json.loads(shared_data)
print(result['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['user']['media']['nodes'][0]['caption'])
```

Result:
LAST CALL: Enter for a chance to meet President Obama this summer before tonight's deadline. → Link in profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code below, you're only retrieving the first node (which is the first image).

```
print(result['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['user']['media']['nodes'][0]['caption'])
```

To get the info of the recent 10 images of the user try this instead.

```
recent_ten_nodes = result['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['user']['media']['nodes'][:10]
```

To only print the captions, number of likes and comments do this.

```
for node in recent_ten_nodes:
    print node['caption']
    print node['likes']['count']
    print node['comments']['count']
```

For storing of these values, it's up to you to decide how you want to store them.

Comment: Getting this:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: My bad. I've edited my answer. Do let me know if the updated answer works :)